# Android game background?

Tags: android, animation, graphics

I'm making a game in android in which a character is running. But the problem is that the part of the background that is no longer shown in the screen is not repeating.

This is my code

```
    ImageView background1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background1);
    ImageView background2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background2);
    ImageView background3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background3);

    TranslateAnimation anim_back1 = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, -300, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    TranslateAnimation anim_back2 = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, -300, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    TranslateAnimation anim_back3 = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, -10, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    anim_back1.setDuration(10000);
    anim_back1.setFillEnabled(true);

    anim_back2.setDuration(7000);
    anim_back2.setFillEnabled(true);

    anim_back3.setDuration(4000);
    anim_back3.setFillEnabled(true);            

    background1.startAnimation(anim_back1);
    background2.startAnimation(anim_back2);
    background3.startAnimation(anim_back3);
```

Comment: Please use third party `game engine` like `andengine` or `Unity-3D`..!!

Answer (score 0):

Standart views is not very suitable for the game creation. If you don't need to use OpenGL then use SurfaceView and draw your game on Canvas. There is control animation and drawing more easy. If I remember true it has game engine to work with canvas.

Of course, you can create a some count of ImageView to fill screen and transfer their but it is not optimal. Then at least create custom view which will draw your background more effective.

P.S. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: can you please send me an example with the code. because i am new in android coding so please help me... :P

Comment: If you don't want to use game engine then use lesson how to create custom view: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html